# The prefix "ref" for element "ref:setting" is not bound

Tags: xml, xslt

Im encountering the error when trying to transform the following XML:

```
<triggers>
<add status="Success">
    <from>
        <ref:setting name = ".technicalContactEmail"/>
    </from>
    <recipients>
        <ref:maintenanceJob out="creatorEmail"/>
    </recipients>
    <subject> Your download has been prepared</subject>
    <body>
        <ref:downloadOrderInfo out="downloadsUrl" store="@downloadsUrl"/>
        <div style="color: #5C9731; font-size: 18pt; font-family: tahoma; margin-bottom: 15px;">    Your <ref:downloadOrderInfo out="fileNameLabel"/> (<ref:downloadOrderInfo out="fileName"/>) has been prepared. Please go to <a href="@downloadsUrl">My downloads page</a> in XXXX to download it.</div>
        <br/>
        <div>***This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply to this message. ***</div>
    </body>
</add>
<add status="PartiallyFailed, Failed">
    <from>
        <ref:setting name = ".technicalContactEmail"/>
    </from>
    <recipients>
        <ref:maintenanceJob out="creatorEmail"/>
    </recipients>
    <subject> Error when preparing download</subject>
    <body>
        <ref:downloadOrderInfo out="downloadsUrl" store="@downloadsUrl"/>
        <div style="color: #5C9731; font-size: 18pt; font-family: tahoma; margin-bottom: 15px;">    An error occurred while preparing the <ref:downloadOrderInfo out="fileNameLabel"/>: <ref:downloadOrderInfo out="fileName"/>. You can retry and request the download again on the <a href="@downloadsUrl">My downloads page</a> in XXXX.</div>
        <br/>
        <div>***This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply to this message. ***</div>
    </body>
</add>
```

with this XLST script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="from"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Objective is to remove "from" XML tag but I'm encountering the error 
**The prefix "ref" for element "ref:setting" is not bound.**

Note that I cant modify the XML entry just the XSLT.

Comment: How do you create the XML or how do you receive it? Did you eliminate some element containing something like `xmlns:ref="example.org"` in another procedure before?

Comment: its from SQL, its an email template. Im not aware of any xmlns:ref element. I did the XLST from scratch.

Comment: Can you manipulate the source XML (which is not well formed, at least not in the given example) in a way that you surround it with a root element before processing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your source XML contains namespaces, you must specify them,
e.g. in the root tag. Otherwise such an XML has improper structure.

In your case there is one namespace - `ref`, so change your `triggers`
tag to e.g.

```
<triggers xmlns:ref="dummy.com">
```

(or other URN) and it will be OK.

**Note**: If your XSLT script contained a reference to any namespace from
the source XML, you would have to specify this namespace also in XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT isn't going to help you transform something that isn't well-formed XML.

When you get bad XML your first thought should always be, where did this come from and can we fix the source to produce good XML in future?

If you can't get it fixed, you should be worrying about the fact that you are dependent on a supplier who is delivering faulty goods.

If the worst comes to the worst, you can consider repairing the bad XML. The strategy for repair depends on how regular and predictable the corruptions are, and on what repair action is appropriate. Unfortunately you'll probably have to use non-XML tools (e.g. Perl scripts) for the repair job since most XML tools only work on well-formed XML.

Some kinds of repairs can be effected using tools such as HTML Tidy or validator.nu. I don't know if they will help you in this case.

In this particular case I would probably do the repair by adding a line

```
<wrapper xmlns:ref="something">
```

at the top and a corresponding

```
</wrapper>
```

at the bottom, and then use XSLT for the rest of the job.

Answer (score 0):

I also added  this code on the XSLT on top on what Valdi_Bo suggested and it works now. 
I'll suggest to the management that we need to add the reference on the XML.
Thanks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ref="dummy.com">
```